# How can I store and retrieve many javascript primitives in and from local storage

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

My application has the following Javascript primatives:

```
var bearerToken = "a";
var expirationDate = "b";
var firstName = "c";
var authenticated = true;
var lastName = "d";
var loginMessage = "e";
var name = "f";
var registrationMessage = "g";
var roleId = 1;
var subjectId = 2;
var userName = "h"
```

I would like to hold a copy of these in local storage. I know how to do it for one at a time but is there a way I could do it for all of them at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use `JSON.stringify` and store the object as a string. Use `JSON.parse` to retrieve it:

```
var o = {
    bearerToken: 'Foo',
    authenticate: true,
    subjectId: 3
}
localStorage.setItem('myData', JSON.stringify(o));
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myData')));
```

Answer (score 2):

Make an object and store them on the same object

```
var someObj = {lastName:'test',firstname:'joe'};
```

Just add all the properties to the object like above.

You can store it as a json string

```
localStorage.setItem('someName', JSON.stringify(someObj));
```

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage.setItem("bearerToken","")` will help you to save an item in the local storage.
`localStorage.getItem("bearerToken")` will retrieve that value
`localStorage.removeItem("bearerToken")` will remove that item.

Comment: Hi, Did you see my comment about "is there a way I could do it for all of them at the same time" :-)

Comment: oops! excuse me for that! anyways you got your solution which is good :-)