# How can I store and retrieve many javascript variables in and from local storage

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

My application has the following Javascript variables:

```
var bearerToken = "a";
var expirationDate = "b";
var firstName = "c";
var authenticated = true;
var lastName = "d";
var loginMessage = "e";
var name = "f";
var registrationMessage = "g";
var roleId = 1;
var subjectId = 2;
var userName = "h"
```

I would like to hold a copy of all of these **combined** in one place in local storage. I only need to be able to do three things to this. Put all of them to the local store. Retrieve all of them from the local store and delete all of them from the local store.

I know how to do it for one at a time but is there a way I could do it for **all of them at the same time** and store them in one single local storage store.

Note: This is similar to my last question that was perhaps not clear. As I had answers for that I accepted the one that was correct and have created this new question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I store and retrieve many javascript primitives in and from local storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27119400/how-can-i-store-and-retrieve-many-javascript-primitives-in-and-from-local-storag)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27119450/139300

Comment: @CD - Did you see my comment at the end. This question is on how to combine all of them together and store them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the objects wrapped in JSON:

```
var account = {};
account.bearerToken = "a";
account.expirationDate = "b";
account.firstName = "c";
account.authenticated = true;
account.lastName = "d";
account.loginMessage = "e";
account.name = "f";
account.registrationMessage = "g";
account.roleId = 1;
account.subjectId = 2;
account.userName = "h";

localStorage.setItem('account', JSON.stringify(account));
var loadedAccount = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('account'));
```